# Floating image after last word

Tags: css

I want image (rating stars) to float always to the and of the title.
But when is title to big (two rows), image is on next row, not on last word.

Is there any way to float image after dot of last word?

http://jsfiddle.net/MJgU4/1/

```
<h1>This is short text</h1><span>float image</span>
<br /><br />
<h1>This is long text. This is long text. This is long text. This is long text. This is long text. This is long text. This is long text.This is long text.</h1><span>float image</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is set h1 tags to be displayed as inline elements. You confuse how the browser flows the diferents elements. The browser introduce a linebreak when renders block elements (like h1) so you need to display the headers as inline elements.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aleruar/U5yJF/)

```
code fiddle
```

Comment: Thanks. I was working in the drupal, and rate module adds prefix divs with some display:block elements. When I force it to the inline, everything was ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to show up directly after the text, you can include it in the `<h1>` tag. That way it will be displayed inline. See this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJgU4/4/):

```
<div>
    <h1>This is short text<span>float image</span></h1>
</div>
<div>

<h1>This is long text. This is long text. 
      This is long text. This is long text. This is long text. 
      This is long text. This is long text.
      This is long text.<span>float image</span></h1>
</div>
```

No need to float the image tag.

Comment: Thanks. I was working in the drupal, and rate module adds prefix divs with some display:block elements. When I force it to the inline, everything was ok.